# ajax form validation in laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am new in laravel and need help.

These are the values I'm getting via ajax, all values are to be stored in db, but how do I validate[check] if there are existing values or not before submitting a form using ajax?

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "{!! URL::to('/') !!}";
        var id="{!! @$department->id !!}";
        var token = "{!! csrf_token() !!}";
        var customer_id = $("#customer_id").val();
        var visiting_address1 = $("#visiting_address1").val();
            var department_id = $("#department_id").val();  

        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url+"/customer/"+customer_id+"/popup_store",  
            data: { '_token':token, 'rest':'true', 'customer_id':$("#customer_id").val(), 'main_address':$("#main_address").val(),'visiting_city':$("#visiting_city").val(),'visiting_address':$("#visiting_address1").val(),'visiting_zip':$("#visiting_zip").val()},
            async : false,
            success : function(data) { 
            if(data == "success")
            {
                $("#addrecords").modal('hide');

            }
            else 
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Please try to be more clear with your question in future, it was very confusing to read.  Are you trying to validate form data, or verify whether there are duplicates?

Comment: Hi Tim Ogilvy avoid duplicates values

Comment: only unique values

Comment: So you only want to add a new popup store if there isn't one already with the same name?

Comment: Have a bit of a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139076/laravel-update-if-record-exists-or-create-if-not and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839941/insert-a-new-record-if-not-exist-and-update-if-exist-laravel-eloquent, maybe there will be some ideas.

Comment: Tim Ogilvy i am asking how to avoid duplicate values  using ajax

Comment: What is the desired functionality if you do find a duplicate via ajax?

Comment: i am using popup modal window , so i getting value from ajax way

Answer (score 0):

First of all define you `Jquery validation` for you form like this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        name: "required",
    },
    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter name",
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        // leave it blank here.
    }
});
```

And then in your `click` button of `submit` button, write if condition to check validations:

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {
    if ($('#myForm').valid()) {
        // your Ajax Call Code
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Ali i have try your idea but not working properly

Comment: Ali actually two form page one is order form page another one is department from page, here in my order form page la apply modal popup plus button are you understand Ali

Comment: then  when i press plus button open modal window . that values are getting from Ajax  see abowe my ajax code

Comment: Can't get u actually.

Comment: what i am expecting that record exist or not, if existing record means show message or alert

Comment: Ali i am getting  all values from modal popup and store to database also Ali

Comment: how to check existing record or not using ajax way or any other idea Ali